# I have something not working with my looping. it can run but its not looping

Tags: java, loops

```
while (input != '1'){
    String customer;
    customer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer's name: ");

    String type;
    type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose type of photocopy: G/C");

    if (type.equals("G")) {
        noOfPhotocopy = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("Enter no of photocopy: "));

        if (noOfPhotocopy < 10) {
            totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.10;
        } else if (noOfPhotocopy >= 10) {
            totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.05;
        }
    } else if (type.equals("C")) {
        noOfPhotocopy = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter no of photocopy: "));

        if (noOfPhotocopy < 10) {
            totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.20;
        } else if (noOfPhotocopy >= 10) {
            totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.10;
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer name : "+customer+"\nType of Photocopy : "+type+"\nNumber of Photocopy : "+noOfPhotocopy+"\nTotal Price : RM"+ (float)totalprice);

    String input1;
    input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Press 1 to stop or press anything to continue ");
    input = Integer.parseInt(input1);
    break;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Program finished ^^");
```

Please help me with this code.  I cannot determine what is wrong with this code.  When I run this program, it seems that the looping is not working.  This is my assignment project and need to be submit earlier.

Why is my loop not looping?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: you are checking for '1' bur the variable has integer 1. May be thats the reason

Comment: I think you want to understand what [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) is doing to your loop

Comment: You have used `break;` as the last statement, thats why After executing while loop for one time the loop break. Please use break in a particular case i.e. when you want to quit or break from the loop.

Comment: In your program i think you don't need to use break, if input variable is updated inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You **break** unconditionally.  **break** will always exit the enclosing loop.

Also you have a type confusion in your loop condition between **char** and **int**.  It is legal due to type coercion (**int** will be converted to **char** for comparison or vice versa), but it won't do what you intend.

```
'1'
```

is a **char**.  It's a UTF-16 character whose **int** value is **49**.

```
1
```

is an **int**

You really want this:

```
while (input != 1) {
```

Here's another way to approach this that you can apply generally when programs go pear-shaped (don't work as expected).

Make a backup of this code and start a new Java class.  In that class create a smaller example.  Maybe something like this:

```
while (input != '1') {
    String input1;
    input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Press 1 to stop or press anything to continue ");
    input = Integer.parseInt(input1);
    break;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Program finished ^^");
```

This program has the same bugs, but is much smaller.  Can you see the problem in that smaller program?

This approach done either by removing code or commenting it out allows you to isolate a bug by trial and error.  Over time you'll develop an intuition for the bugs and see them immediately, but this approach goves you an avenue for getting to that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (input !='1'){
```

is wrong. Because `input` is `int`. Inside your code you write:

```
input = Integer.parseInt(input1); // so input is int type
```

Rewrite it as:

```
while (input != 1){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int input=1;
Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Start!!!");
while (input!=0) {
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit!!");
    input=scn.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Finish!!!");
```

Refer this code for your code.
No need to use **break** inside loop. You can use it with conditional break.